# Get the selected item in a listbox

Tags: vb6

I am new to VB6. I need to get the selected item in a listbox
to set its content to be the text of a textbox when I press the `Modify` button.

```
Private Sub Modify_Click()
    List2.List(0) = Text3.Text
End Sub
```

I need to change index 0 for the selected item from the listbox.

In VB.Net, I used the following statement but, in VB6, I don't know how to do it.

```
val=ListBox2.SelectedItem.Value
```

Answer (score 5):

`ListIndex` returns the zero-based index of the selected item or `-1` if no item is selected. Use it in conjunction with the `List()` collection to retrieve the selected item.

For example:

```
If List2.ListIndex < 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No item selected."
Else
    Debug.Print "Selected text = " & List2.List(List2.ListIndex)
End If
```

Or, you can just use the `Text` property. If no item is selected, `Text` will return an empty string.

```
Debug.Print List2.Text
```

If your `ListBox` allows for multiple selections, you'll need to loop through the items and use the `Selected()` function to determine which are selected:

```
For i = 0 To List2.ListCount - 1
    If List2.Selected(i) Then Debug.Print List2.List(i)
Next
```

So, to answer your question, to change the text of the selected item to that of your textbox, use the following:

```
If List2.ListIndex >= 0 Then
    List2.List(List2.ListIndex) = Text3.Text
End If
```